# What's the command line for clicking on the 'Connect' button of rasphone.pbk?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, internet-connection

C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk
Do you know the command line for clicking on the 'Connect' button of it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Each time after Windows startup, I have to manually run rasphone.pbk and then click on the 'Connect' button so as to use the connection. I want to create a task in the Task Scheduler, whereby 'Connect' can be done automatically. I know the path is "C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk" but I don't know the command line. Do you know it?

Comment: Do you mean you need the command that runs when you double click on a `*.pbk` file?

Comment: @  Kevin Panko 9, I have solved the problem by using `Rasdial "connection name" "user name" "password"`. I wanted connection to be done automatically.